# How to start bot locally - Bot framework composer developer setup

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, power-virtual-agents

I have just started working with PVA and Bot framework composer.
I have hooked my Bot project up with a PVA bot. Before I had a fully local Bot framework composer where I could start the bot locally and test it. But now that I have moved my bot over to PVA I'm no longer able to start the bot through Bot framework composer.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MHXg.png)

The error message I get is that I need to publish the bot and test it in PVA.
But this is a very long and time consuming process for fast develop iterations.
Is there a smart way to setup a good developer enviornment for Bot framework composer.
Any help and links to guides are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SupportBryan on the official forum have answered my question.
Here is the link to the topic: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PVA-chatbots-in/Bot-framework-composer-developer-setup-for-PVA-in-Teams/m-p/1550337#M712